# shifting a DIV under position:fixed divs

Tags: html, css-position, move

I'm not entirely sure how to explain my question, so I'll just provide you with a demo of my problem: http://voxldesigns.com/jbg-test/

As you can see, the two header bars are overlapping the text area. How would I shift the text area downwards so it is underneath the header bars, without overlapping?

Thanks.

Comment: is z index is what you are looking for?...

Comment: No, I don't believe so. I don't want the text area to be stacked under the header bars. I want the position (in a 2D space) to be under it.